# Storage Case or Organization Method for Sticks of RAM

Tags: memory, work-environment

I have piles of RAM scattered around my work area.

Currently, they're not organized very well, nor protected against ESD.

I was hoping to find out what others did to organize their piles of spare RAM. I was envisioning some sort of special storage case with slots for each stick, but I wasn't able to turn up anything like that.

How do you store your spare RAM?

Comment: I wrapped mine in a sheet of paper. Either one per sheet or 2,3,4 equal into one sheet, in a way that paper is between them. Not perfect, but works very well and you can label it on the outside.

Answer (score 2):

We either store them in the antistatic trays they are delivered in:

[image: Antistatic RAM Tray]

Or in a [antistatic bags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antistatic_bag):

[image: Antistatic Bag]

Comment: I have access to neither, unfortunately. Are you able to get the tray through retail distributors (without RAM in it)?

Comment: @ForceFlow Your best bet may be to check eBay, or go to a local computer store and see if they have any extras.